# Is for loop suitable for functions?

Tags: procedural-programming

I have a question about for loop. 
In this example i made For loop without function, like this

```
    list = RandomInteger[10, 20]
a = Length[list];
For[i = 1, i < a + 1, i++,
 If[list[[i]] >= 5, list[[i]] = list[[i]]^2, 
  list[[i]] = list[[i]]^0.5];
 Print["iteration ", i, ", " , list[[i]]]
 ]
```

the code is working corectly.
But, when I put For loop inside the function like this

```
    list = RandomInteger[10, 10];
function[list_] := Module[{a = Length[list]},
  For[i = 1, i < a + 1 , i++, 
   If[list[[i]] >= 5, list[[i]] = list[[i]]^2, 
    list[[i]] = list[[i]]^0.5];
   Print["iteration ", i, ", ", list[[]]]
   ]
  ]
function[list]
```

than I get an error.
Why is this happening. Is for loop suitable for functions?

Comment: The use of `For`-loops and friends is heavily discouraged in Mathematica. Have a look at `Map`, `Apply`, `Fold`,... instead.

Comment: Speaking figuratively, >90% probability, NO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using `SetAttributes`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171098/34008) is an overkill. (As discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171103/34008).)

Here is a more direct way of getting the desired outcome in the way you want:

```
list = RandomInteger[10, 10];
function[listArg_] :=
 Module[{list = listArg, a},
  a = Length[list];
  For[i = 1, i < a + 1, i++, 
   If[list[[i]] >= 5, list[[i]] = list[[i]]^2, 
    list[[i]] = list[[i]]^0.5];
   Print["iteration ", i, ", ", list[[]]]]
  ]
function[list]
```

Now I would say that a more functional way is this one:

```
function[list_] :=
 FoldList[(
    Echo[{#2, 
       ReplacePart[#1, #2 -> 
         If[#1[[#2]] >= 5, #1[[#2]]^2, #1[[#2]]^0.5]]}, 
      "{iteration,result}="][[2]]
    ) &, list, Range[Length[list]]]
```

But that might be too complicated for someone with only imperative programming background ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can see that you know a lot about his program. I have read two books about wolfram mathematica, one is "Programming with mathematica , and introduction" and "Hands‑On Start to Wolfram Mathematica: ". I have learned a lot but I would like to get some more knowledge. What would you suggest me to read or do next?

Comment: @user57225 I am not sure I can offer better books. The books I used 25 years ago are still actual when it comes to functional programming with Mathematica, but, of course, use much less core functions and functionalities. The book ["Applied Mathematica: Getting Started, Getting It Done"](https://www.amazon.com/Applied-Mathematica-Getting-Started-Done/dp/020154217X) was very helpful because it is concise. [The Roman Maeder books](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?field-keywords=Roman+Maeder) are good sources of learning programming in Mathematica too.

Answer (score 5):

Normal functions are not allowed to modify their argument. But you can give the attribute `HoldAll` to your function in order to enable what is called call by reference:

```
list = RandomInteger[10, 10];

ClearAll[function];(*erases all definitions for f*)
SetAttributes[function, HoldAll]
function[list_] := 
 Module[{a = Length[list]}, 
  For[i = 1, i < a + 1, i++, 
   If[list[[i]] >= 5, list[[i]] = list[[i]]^2, 
    list[[i]] = list[[i]]^0.5];
   Print["iteration ", i, ", ", list]]]
function[list]
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

While Henriks answer is a correct and precise answer to your actual question I wanted to add some extra information why you usually need to use `SetAttributes` only very rarely and how that is related with the suggestion to avoid `For` loops, and in fact many typical approaches you might have learned from writing procedural code in other languages.

Here is how you probably would write a function which calculates the same numbers as your functions:

```
 function[list_] := Map[If[# >= 5, #^2, #^0.5] &, list]
```

It admittedly doesn't exactly do what your function does but typically it makes more sense for a function to return something than to print what it does.
The function definition shows two things which are very common in Mathematica code: instead of manipulating the list the function returns a new list with the result and it prefers functional over procedural constructs when possible. Because a new list is returned instead of manipulating the input no `SetAttributes` is needed. Once you get used to those patterns, you will need to "pass by reference" only in very special and rare circumstances.